# Have event for another open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet template that is sent out to customers. Since it is sent to a third party, the spreadsheet cannot have any macros in it.  What I would like to accomplish is once the spreadsheet is sent back to me, have the ability to tie a macro I wrote to double clicking a cell in the returned spreadsheet (the macro is stored in a separate spreadsheet I have). Is it possible to have one spreadsheet watch events on another open spreadsheet?

Comment: In short - yes; a macro-enabled workbook (the one you keep on your computer) can refer to a non-macro-enabled workbook (the one your third party will send back to you).

Comment: Thanks,  I know i can refer to it, however the problem is that i need an event listener for the sheet without macros.  Meaning, when the returned sheet without macros is double clicked, it fires the macro on the sheet that has the stored macro.

Comment: You need to create a custom class with a WithEvents worksheet member, and set the member to the non-macro sheet.

Comment: Thanks Excel Developers, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard code module:

```
Public mySheetClass as new CustomSheet

Public Sub Init()
    Set mySheetClass.mySheet = NonMacroWorkbook.WorkSheets("TheSheet")
End Sub
```

In a class module, named CustomSheet:

```
Public WithEvents mySheet As Worksheet

Private Sub mySheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Foo"
End Sub
```

Then run Init.